# How can i get the statement out of the pqxx::prepare::invocation as std::string?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

Example:

```
    pqxx::connection c("dbname=mydb user=user");
    pqxx::work w(c);

    c.prepare("Prepared_Statement", "SELECT id  FROM mytable WHERE id = $1 or id = $2");

    pqxx::prepare::invocation w_invocation = w.prepared("Prepared_Statement");
```

But i can not declare a cursor with this statement where it expects a query as std::string :

```
    pqxx::stateless_cursor<pqxx::cursor_base::read_only, pqxx::cursor_base::loose> cursor(w, w_invocation , "cname", false);
```

Comment: same question but more constructive, unanswered in 2007. Might be a good hint http://lists.pgfoundry.org/pipermail/libpqxx-general/2007-September/000006.html